# Inserting if statement inside ES6 template literal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

I have a simple ajax request returning some data and then inserting into a template literal. I was wondering if it it possible to insert an 'if' statement inside the template?

Essentially to add a further line of code, if the json object has a 5th color.

```
  $.ajax({
url: 'http://localhost:8888/ColourCatchr%202/app/search.php'
}).done(function(results){
var res = jQuery.parseJSON(results);
console.log(res);
$.each(res,function(index,result){
  $('.palettes').append(`
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">${result.name}</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="col-md-12 colors">
          <div class="color" style=background-color:#${result['color 1']}><h6>${result['color 1']}</h6></div>
          <div class="color" style=background-color:#${result['color 2']}><h6>${result['color 2']}</h6></div>
          <div class="color" style=background-color:#${result['color 3']}><h6>${result['color 3']}</h6></div>
          <div class="color" style=background-color:#${result['color 4']}><h6>${result['color 4']}</h6></div>

          ${if(result['color 5']){
            <div class="color" style=background-color:#${result['color 5']}><h6>${result['color 5']}</h6></div>
            }
          }

          <div class="color" style=background-color:#${result['color 5']}><h6>${result['color 5']}</h6></div>
          <p>on hover change to translucent background and black text for ecah color</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-footer">
          <a class="btn btn-info btn-lg" href="update.html?id=${result.id}">Edit</a>
          <a class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Delete</a>
      </div>
    </div>`
    )
})

})
```

Comment: *"if it it possible to insert an 'if' statement inside the template"* It's not. You can only use *expressions* inside template literals.

Comment: Don't append markup in a loop. This leads to lots of unnecessary render cycles, pretty much the worst thing you can do in terms of JS performance. Use `var rows = $.map(res, function(result){ return ... })` to generate all the markup first, and then `$('.palettes').append(rows.join(''))` to append all the generated markup at once.

Comment: @Thomas thanks for this. Just implemented this and it does work much better!

Answer (score 115, accepted):

You'll need to move your logic into a function or use the ternary operator:

```
`${result['color 5'] ? 'color 5 exists!' : 'color 5 does not exist!'}`
```

Additional example based on comment:

```
`${result['color 5'] ? 
    `<div class="color" style=background-color:#${result['color 5']}><h6>${result['color 5']}</h6></div>` 
: ''}`
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Ternary operator works perfectly except I can only get it to work for strings not returning HTML. Sorry for the silly question, but what am I missing? Do I need to escape certain characters?

Just for clarity I'm trying to show the following HTML:
<div class="color" style=background-color:#${result['color 5']}><h6>${result['color 5']}</h6></div>

Comment: I added an additional example that appears to work for me (I did not test it with jQuery's append method).

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you again. I didnt realise you needed to use back ticks again to insert the HTML.

Comment: @AndyGaskell Love it!

Answer (score 31):

From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) article on template strings:

> Template literals are string literals allowing embedded **expressions**.

So, you can also use an IIFE (immediately invoked function **expression**). Eg: `(() => { ... })()`.

Though, I would argue that if you need more complicated logic than a ternary expression within your template strings, you should consider refactoring your code. However, since this hasn't been presented by the other answers, here's an approach using IIFEs. This can be useful in cases where a ternary expression would suffice, but you prefer reading your branching logic in imperitive form; or in cases where you're embedding other multi-line template strings.

Let me make up an example for you:

```
/* Note: I'm using a tagged template literal for HTML templates here, 
 * similar to the one provided by www.npmjs.com/package/lit-html. 
 */

html`
  <div class="example">
    ${(() => {
      if (result['color 5']) {
        return html`
          <div class="color-preview" style="background-color: ${result['color 5']}"></div>
          <span> Here's your color #5 </span>
        `
      } else {
        return html`<div>You don't have a 5th color</div>`
      }
    })()}
  </div>
`
```

Since a function body can contain more than only expressions, this technique allows you to use any JavaScript syntax "within" your template string.

Comment: If you go this path, remember the `else` - else you'll likely to get an `undefined`

Answer (score 6):

you can use the nullish coalescing operator inside the template literal.

```
`${result['color 5'] ?? `Color 5 exists`}`
```

A better way is to create default parameters for the function.

```
const renderHello = (name = "new member") => `Hello ${name}`;

console.log(1, renderHello());
console.log(2, renderHello("James"));
// 1 Hello new member
// 2 Hello James
```

Comment: This is actually incorrect. If `result['color 5']` is undefined, the string literal renders "undefined". My Bad.

Comment: You can do `!!result['color 5']` to check it as bool type.

Comment: Even as a boolean you still get false as a string

Answer (score 5):

There may be times you don't want to render anything if the condition is `false`, like how you have it in your question. You can therefore do something like this:

(Note: it's also possible to nest template literals inside each other when the nested one is inside a `${}`)

```
const html = `
  <div>
    <div>
      Lots of HTML stuff
    </div>
    <div>

    ${result['color 5'] && `
      <div class="color" style=background-color:#${result['color 5']}><h6>${result['color 5']}</h6></div>
    `}
  </div>
`;
```

This works because, unlike other languages, in Javascript, logical operators (`&&` and `||`) do not (necessarily) return `true` or `false`.

**The logical AND operator (`&&`)**:

Javascript returns either the first [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) variable, and if none are found, the last [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) variable.

**The logical OR operator (`||`)**

Javascript returns either the first truthy variable, and if none are found, the last falsy variable.

You can see this in action here:

```js
console.log(true && true) // true
console.log(false && true) // false    
console.log("a" && "b"); // b
console.log(false && "b"); // false
console.log(0 && "b"); // 0
console.log("a" && NaN); // NaN
```

This is used very commonly in JSX.

Answer (score 2):

To use a variable while using the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), use a [nested template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) like this:

```js
let var1 = 6
let var2 = 8

console.log(`${ `${var1 > var2 ? var1 + ` (var1) `: var2 + ` (var2) `}` } is greater`)
```

Comment: SonarQube discourages uses of nested template literals, if you have sonarqube analysis in your codebase, please avoid using this. Sonarqube  analysis reads "Its possible to build complex string literals by nesting together multiple template literals, and therefore lose readability and maintainability.In such situations, it’s preferable to move the nested template into a separate statement."

Answer (score 0):

```
const heading = 'head';
const location = 'erode';
const district = 'erode';

const isSameLocationDistrict = (location === district) || false;
const storeSlug = `${heading} ${isSameLocationDistrict === true ? location : `${location } ${district}`}`;
console.log(storeSlug);

// "head erode"
// "head erode1 erode"
```